# custom fields in csv

Tags: grails, csv, dns

I want to put only certain fields of domain in csv being generated. how can that be done?

I have a order class which contains before update and afterInsert. I have kept them as transient. but still their names comes in the header also, I also want only 5 of the feilds to appear in the csv not all.

Comment: What CSV? Grails - to my knowledge - doesn't have support for CSV out of the box, are you talking about some plugin?

Comment: I am using export plugin to create the csv which takes in a list of object. But my problem is I dont want all fields of the domain. only a few and also want the afterUpdate and beforeUpdates to not come in the header of csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which fields to export. An example for this can be found in [Grails Export Plugin documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/export).

Comment: thank you so much, is there any method to use data from multiple domain into same csv?

Comment: ERR :No signature of method: de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportService.export() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.RoutableServletOutputStream, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [csv, com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.RoutableServletOutputStream@186686b5, [com.ds.store.OrderInfo : 1], [id, dateCreated, status], [id:Order Id, dateCreated:date Of Order, status:Status of order]]
Possible solutions: export(java.lang.String, java.io.OutputStream, java.util.List, java.util.Map, java.util.Map)

Comment: response.contentType ='text/csv'
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Details.csv")
    List fields = ["id", "dateCreated","status"]
    Map labels = ["id": "Order Id", "dateCreated": "date Of Order","status":"Status of order"]
    exportService.export('csv', response.outputStream,resultantOrder.order,fields,labels)//[:],[:])

Comment: you need to pass formatters and parameters, too. Try uncommenting last two passed maps, this: `exportService.export('csv', response.outputStream, resultantOrder.order, fields, labels, [:], [:])` should work.

Comment: and if I want data from different domain( some domain with relation hasMany)'s data in same csv?